# Why restTemplateBuilder is not loaded in Spring Boot 2.2.4?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade SpringBoot from 2.1.1 to 2.2.4.RELEASE. 
I found an issue I can't solve.
When I try to run integration tests I run into an error:

> - Bean method 'restTemplateBuilder' in 'RestTemplateAutoConfiguration' not loaded because NoneNestedConditions 1 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition.ReactiveWebApplication found ReactiveWebApplicationContext

This is my class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RoutesIT {
```

I noticed that a new `@Conditional(NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition.class)` is added to `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class` and this is probably the reason why `restTemplateBuilder` is not loaded properly.

I can create this bean manually but I don't think that's the best solution.
What should I do to make it work again?

Comment: It fails only in the test, everything still works when you boot the application normally?

Comment: @Gimby yes, gradle bootRun works fine.

Comment: I don't know what more I can share with you.
I am creating a bean like this:

Bean
    public RestTemplate someRest(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        //some logic

        RestTemplate restTemplate = builder
            .requestFactory(() ->
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client)))
            .build();

        return restTemplate;
    }

and then Autowired with Qualified in RoutesIT

Comment: @Gimby We need to know that I have this bean only inside integration-test location. It means that when I run bootRun spring boot doesn't create this bean. It should only be created when trying to run integration tests.

Comment: Aaaah, I did not consider that fact. Don't put code in comments by the way, edit it into the question so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Your application context is of reactive type for restTemplateBuilder it should be non reactive.

Comment: See anything causing this to be reactive or you can use webClientBuilder or set WebApplicationType explicitly

Comment: @NirajJha could you tell me how to do this? I tried with spring.main.web-application-type: servlet and spring.main.web-application-type: none and still without success. I have excluded spring-boot-starter-webflux from spring-cloud-starter-gateway and still nothing.

Comment: I use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT) which probably under the hood creates a reactive web application.

Comment: Have you checked is webflux jar in your classpath?

Comment: Right now no - I've excluded webflux from my classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should use `WebClient` instead of `RestTemplate` when you are reactive. See documentation here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client

But if you have other reasons to keep on using `RestTemplate` add this class into your test package:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
    // Need to provide a rest template builder because
    // @RestTemplateAutoConfiguration does not work with webflux
    return new RestTemplateBuilder();
  }

}
```